# Volcado hexadecimal de un directorio en Linux

Tags: linux

Para resolver un problema de codificación de caracteres en nombres de ficheros, necesito encontrar una forma de hacer un volcado hexadecimal de un directorio en Linux, ya que los comandos `hexdump` y similares dan error con directorios:

```
$ hexdump -C .
    hexdump: .: Es un directorio
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo? Gracias por adelantado.